# viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager); returns NULL, how to use .addNext() and .showNext()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-view

I'm trying to instantiate a viewpager in my app but I can't find a way to make the viewpager object non-null. Everytime I call `viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);` from my onCreate() method in my main activity, the viewpager object returned is null. Why is this?

I'm doing some view manipulation in an AsyncTask thread that launches before this and displays a splash screen in addition to loading some files. In this thread I manipulate the view using a ViewSwitcher object and built in methods such as .addView().
**LoadNoteFiles.java**

```
protected void onPreExecute(){
    PlayFrets.viewSwitch = new ViewSwitcher(mContext);
            PlayFrets.viewSwitch.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(mContext, R.layout.splash_screen, null));
            instance = (Activity)mContext;  //cast context from main activity into an activity to access setContentView method
            instance.setContentView(PlayFrets.viewSwitch);
        }
...

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
            PlayFrets.viewSwitch.addView(ViewSwitcher.inflate(mContext, R.layout.activity_play_frets, null));
            PlayFrets.viewSwitch.showNext();
            ((PlayFrets)mContext).configFretboard();
        }
```

Should I be trying to add each menu fragment View to the ViewSwitcher object using .addView()? What is causing my viewPager to always be null? I'm not very clear on when and how I need to use a ViewSwitcher object and methods like .addView() and .showNext(), so some background explanation for that would be wonderful.Below are my xml files and some relevant code from my main activity.

**PlayFrets.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  //sets activity orientation to portrait
        //Build GUI
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);           //Removes action bar from display
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  //Removes status bar from display


        //Create AsyncTask to load the note files. A splash screen will be displayed while task is executing
        new LoadNoteFiles(this).execute();

        //Set up Menu Swipe Capability
        //implements ViewPager class
        viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager); //viewpager null here
        PagerAdapter pageAdapter = new MenuPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);   //causes nullpointer exception here
    }
```

**activity_play_frets.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <LinearLayout    
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/gold_guitarsim_text"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/toolbarGestureOverlay" >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>  

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="4">  
    <com.example.guitarsim.Multitouch
        android:id="@+id/fretBoard"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fret_board1" />
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

**Sample menu fragment xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You forgot `setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_frets)` in your onCreate method. Also check which R you have imported make sure it's your applications not androids or system.

Comment: Since I call instance.setContentView(PlayFrets.viewSwitch); in my AsyncTask I thought I did not need to call setContentView in onCreate(). Confirm/deny?

Comment: You need to call it in onCreate() to be able to access the sub view. You try to find/load the subview before setContentView() is called which will return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my question. The solution was to add `((PlayFrets) mContext).configMenu();` to the end of PostExecute() in my Asynctask. I also added the method

`void configMenu(){      //instantiates a viewpager object
        viewpager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter pageAdapter = new MenuPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    }`

to my main activity class. This way the viewpager successfully latches onto the content view.

Answer (score 0):

call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_frets)
```

after your getWindow() function

Comment: This does not prevent the null pointer exception. I call setContentView in my AsyncTask so that is why it isn't called here.

Comment: When loading the contentView in a thread, there is no guarantee that it will be set before your call in viewpager. Sometimes it may, sometimes it will not. Moreover, you are setting R.layout.activity_play_frets in PostExecute, which is pretty late. What you can try is to implement a callbackfunction which will return to your activity after postexecute completes. Otherwise, move your splashlayout to view within activity_play_frets. And activate it /deactivate it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **set xml view** for particular **Activity**:

In your case you have to **setContentView(Id_Of_Your_Layout)** which **contains** your **Viewpager**.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in LoadNoteFiles.java with instance.setContentView(PlayFrets.viewSwitch). Declaring setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_frets) in onCreate() does not stop viewpager from being nul